# copy value of current object to next object by Iterator

Tags: java, iterator

If I have a `LinkedQueue`, is there any way that I can set the value of current object to the next object, next object' values to next next object... till the last element?

The following code seems can't work with this.

```
LinkedDeque<Example> queue = new LinkedDeque<Example>();

Iterator<Example> iterator = queue.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
    Example ex = iterator.next();
    int x = ex.getX();
    int y = ex.getY();
    Example exNext = iterator.next();
    exNext.set(x);
    exNext.set(Y);
}
```

Comment: Not with an iterator. How depends on what `LinkedDeque` this is. I don't see such a class in the JDK.

Comment: Why are you doing this? While it's doable, it seems like a weird operation, and it's certainly not the kind of thing that fits the idea of a queue or deque. It kind of sounds like you *might* just want to remove the last element and add another copy of the first element to the front or something.

Comment: isnt that the same as getting the first item, duplicating it and adding it the first of the queue?

Comment: @user2357112 I'm making a snake moving around. The queue is actually its body segments, which increment to the front of the queue after eating food. So the snake is formed by head (a single segment) and a body (a queue of segments)... I can make the first segment follows head, and second segment follows first segment. But I can't do it for 3rd segment onward.

Comment: @BjörnKautler It's my own class - with enqueue(E e), dequeue(E e), firstNode(), lastNode() methods.

Comment: @Matt: Instead of representing movement by modifying the location of each segment, it'd be easier and more efficient to just add a new head and remove the tail.

Comment: @user2357112 yea... but all body segments have their own color. so I think I can't simply add a new one and remove the tail. Seems like I must need to iterate through the body and update each position with that of the previous segment.... sorry I didn't tell the whole story at the beginning as the code is quite long.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you call `iterator.next()`, the iterators index is incremented, so you will be moving through your list two objects at a time.

Try introducing a previous variable so you are only calling `iterator.next()` once per iteration of the while loop like this:

```
LinkedDeque<Example> queue = new LinkedDeque<Example>();

Iterator<Example> iterator = queue.iterator();
if(iterator.hasNext()) {
  Example prev = iterator.next();

  while (iterator.hasNext())
  {
      int x = prev.getX();
      int y = prev.getY();
      Example exNext = iterator.next();
      exNext.set(x);
      exNext.set(Y);
      prev = exNext;
  }
}
```

Comment: You'd probably want to save the next element's values before overwriting them.

Comment: Still doesn't work.... only the first segment follows head, but the rest of the segments don't move at all.

Comment: Well, then debug through it. The code here looks good, as long as your own class returns a proper iterator.